# Proof-theoric ordinal of ETCS

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, ordinals, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

What is the proof-theoric ordinal of Lawvere's elementary theory of the category of sets?

Comment: It’s stronger than second order arithmetic iirc so would guess that means “unknown”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current state-of-the-art for proof-theoretic ordinals is somewhere around $\Pi^1_2$-CA$_0$, a subtheory of second-order arithmetic Z$_2$ which in turn is much weaker than ETCS. So at present this is extremely open.

Comment: Whoops, meant 'theory'

Comment: @1103_base_6 Ah, removed that section.